# Python Discord.py client Invalid syntax

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and trying to set a playing status using Python, I've tried different websites like GitHUb and there suggestions ended up in my code and Python didn't seem to like the `await client.change_status(game=discord.Game(name='whatever'))`
Any solutions?

Comment: Line before that has unmatched parentheses.

Comment: You will have to show us a [mcve] that contains code that causes this error and the complete exception, not just a description of it, if you want this debugged.

Comment: If you want wild guesses: are you trying to run this code with Python 2? Or Python 3.3 or something? If not, unmatched parens/brackets/braces are the next most likely guess. Or maybe you have a stray nonprintable character.

Comment: I am trying to run it using Python 3.6.6 due to that being the version working properly with the code that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

#### Next time, please include the error and source code!!!

Alright, with that out of the way, here's my source code that works on `python 3.6` and discord.py `0.16.12`.

```
import discord
import discord.game

client = discord.client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=" with you ;)"))

client.run("<token>")
```

Just merge this with whatever code you have.

[image: It works.]